# How to put a div on the very top of the page using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use a scrolling navigation so as the navigation is folowing the user and no need to go to the top to change the page.

Because the page is an app page, on the very very top of it i want to add something like this :

[image]

My problem is that the scrolling navigation has a really hardcoded css structure, and my question is if there is a javascript/jQuery way to just put that new div block at the top of everything.

Thank you

Comment: Consider adding code to your question. without looking into Code it is really hard to answer you.

Comment: have you try to code with jquery or javascript ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "at the top of everything". Do you want it "glued" to the top of the screen? Do you want to to appear earlier in the document flow? Do you want a pop-out effect where the user have to click it away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can simply try:

```
#new-div-id {
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 999; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
container.insertBefore(newElement, container.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it using CSS

here is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new-div-id").css({"position":"fixed", "top":"0px", "left":"0px", "z-index", 9999 });
});
```